# in OCaml how can I pattern match a function argument while keeping the variable name

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have some code:

```ml
let some_func some_arg = (* ... *)
```

where `some_arg` really needs to be `[| arg1; arg2 |]`. I want to pattern match that in the function argument position, like:

```ml
let some_func [| arg1; arg2 |] = (* ... *)
```

but I also want to keep the variable name `some_arg` in case I want to do something with it directly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function arguments are patterns, so you can use the `as` construct to name parts (or all) of the pattern:

```
let some_func ([| arg1; arg2 |] as some_arg) = (* . . . *)
```

However this pattern isn't exhaustive as it only matches arrays of length 2. So it's a brittle function definition, and you'll get a warning from the compiler.

It might be better just to use a `match` so you can specify the desired behavior when the array is some length other than 2. Or you can use a type that always has exactly 2 components (such as a tuple).

Comment: Please note that `as` will bind to as much of the pattern as it can, so use of parentheses for disambiguation may be necessary.  E.g. in the pattern `fst::snd::rest as lst`, `lst` will be the entire list matched. In the pattern `fst::(snd::rest as tl)`, `tl` will represent everything but the first element in the list.

Comment: Added for the OP's benefit, as I know Jeffrey Scofield is well aware of this.